# How to print concurrent visitors on a website using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In this database, there are data entries which shows login time and logout time of visitors. I want to print the number of concurrent visitors at each entry using sql query preferably by using self join.[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fj25.jpg) The table named "visitor" has  3 columns i.e user_id, login_time amd logout_time. I want to create a 4th column which will show the number of concurrent users during the login_time of that particular entry. In the given example, I have manually displayed the number of concurrent users but I want to write a query which will automatically display the number of concurrent users

Comment: Two rows overlaps when each login time is less than opposite logout time.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Please type in the example here, rather than using an image